# Should I unsubscribe from observables in root Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Observable in my root (bootstrapped) Angular (6.x) component, `AppComponent`.
Normally, I would unsubscribe any open Subscription upon a destroy() call using the lifecycle hook, `ngOnDestroy`.
Since the AppComponent is the root of the application and therefore is never destroyed (except when the entire application is destroyed), do I still need to implement ngOnDestroy and do I need to bother with unsubscribing from my Subscriptions?

I haven't been able to find an answer to this, seemingly common, exact scenario.

Example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private tokenSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private dataSvc: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.tokenSubscription = this.dataSvc.myObservable.subscribe((val) => {
      // do stuff
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.tokenSubscription.unsubscribe(); // Do I need this in root component?
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### One-time Subscriptions in AppComponent.ngOnInit() are Okay

RXJS subscriptions in the Angular `AppComponent` do not need to be unsubscribed, as long as the new Subscriptions are not being repeatedly created. It is fine, for example, if subscriptions are created in `ngOnInit` of `AppComponent` as long as they are one-time actions.

### Angular Services provided in the Root should ideally be [Singleton Services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service)

For Angular services created in the root component, it is ideal to use singleton services to ensure that only one instance exists in the app.

### Best Practices

Although it is generally okay to have subscriptions in the root component that are not unsubscribed, it is recommended to following best practices for managing subscriptions.

- **`take(1)`** - for Subscriptions that only happen **once** during application startup, use RXJS `take(1)` operator, which has the benefit of automatically unsubscribing.
- **`async` Pipe** - handles RXJS subscriptions behind the scenes and automatically unsubscribes.

#### Example using `take(1)`

```
constructor(private dataSvc: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSvc.myObservable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((val) => {
    // do stuff
  });
}
```

See [**The Best Way To Unsubscribe RxJS Observables In The Angular Applications!**](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I do provide services in root as singletons. The included code was merely an example to demonstrate how ngOnDestroy may or may not be needed.